# Using VS 2015/gulp for versioning js files

Tags: angularjs, gulp, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm **using VS 2015, ASP.NET 5 (MVC 6) and Gulp** to write a **SPA with angularjs** and supplementary modules. **My target framework is dnx451.** I've read several best practices which state that the response from Index should have a strict no cache policy set, and all other resources (e.g. js, css, img) should all be heavily cached.  In doing so, the browser always downloads the lightweight page and caches the scripts.  When publishing, **I am trying to have a gulp task which concats/uglifys all my JS files and outputs a single app.min.{version}.js** (also for the less -> css file). This gives the benefit of always downloading the latest file version, but keeping them in cache while it is the latest and greatest.

**Is there a way to get the Version (from project.json) and the build (from the * portion of project.json) from my gulp task?**  I am looking for a way to have the file {version} portion of the name match the version/build of the website.

I have seen examples of using `process.env` in gulp for VS environment variables, but am having trouble putting the pieces together to achieve the desired Version.Build format.

**I have tried:**

```
var project = require('./project.json');
gulp.task('js-publish', function(){
  project.version;  //this give 1.0.0-* (makes sense since its a string)
});
```

**and**

```
gulp.task('js-publish', function(){
  process.env.BUILD_VERSION; //which is undefined
});
```

Comment: this doesn't answer your specific question about naming files with a version, but one option for versioning script files is to use the ScriptTagHelper ie adding asp-append-version="true" to the script tag which should I think automatically append a new version to the url for the script if the file changes on disk so the file name would not have to reflect the version. I'm not 100% sure how it works since I have not seen any documentation for it yet.

Comment: just looked at the source for ScriptTagHelper and for asp-append-version it says: "A query string "v" with the encoded content of the file is added." So the versioning would be automatic with some kind of hash of the file contents used as the version

Comment: Why would you like to change the file on every version/build, especially when nothing changed inside? Use gulp-rev https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rev to have a unique name of your js, which will only be updated when the contents are changed.

Comment: @LiviuCostea - That is a good point.  My intention is to only perform this gulp task on a publish. (On local builds, I include all the scripts individually and do not version them) However, your point is valid in that I don't know if there would ever be a time where I wouldn't manually increment the 'maintenance' portion of the Version in project.json when publishing a version externally.  In this case, splitting the version string on '-' from the first approach I posted would achieve the end goal I want.

Comment: @JoeAudette - I had considered that approach as a backup. My main goal was to be able to readily see if a page was loading the correct version of a script.  This is easier to accomplish if I can see my file as app.min-1.0.0.js

Comment: @LiviuCostea - In addition, **I checked out gulp-rev** and it definitely fits the bill as well.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) NPM package to rename the file. Add gulp-rename to your package.json file. Here is an example of how it can then be used in your gulpfile.js:

```
var rename = require("gulp-rename");

// rename via string 
gulp.src("./src/main/text/hello.txt")
  .pipe(rename("main/text/ciao/goodbye.md"))
  .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist")); // ./dist/main/text/ciao/goodbye.md 

// rename via function 
gulp.src("./src/**/hello.txt")
  .pipe(rename(function (path) {
    path.dirname += "/ciao";
    path.basename += "-goodbye";
    path.extname = ".md"
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist")); // ./dist/main/text/ciao/hello-goodbye.md 

// rename via hash 
gulp.src("./src/main/text/hello.txt", { base: process.cwd() })
  .pipe(rename({
    dirname: "main/text/ciao",
    basename: "aloha",
    prefix: "bonjour-",
    suffix: "-hola",
    extname: ".md"
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist")); // ./dist/main/text/ciao/bonjour-aloha-hola.md
```